# Quadratic Forms and Dual Space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Suppose we have $V$, a finite $k$-vector space, where k is a field with $char(k) \neq 2$. And we have a quadratic form $Q$ on $V$. If $Q$ is non-degenerate then the map $q_v:V \to V^*$ sending $v \in V$ to $w \in V \mapsto (w,v)$, where $(\, ,\, )$ is the symmetric bilinear form associated to $Q$, is surjective.

Now, let $U \subset V$ be a subspace of $V$. Is it true that the canonical map $V^* \to U^*$ is surjective? We would need that every linear form on $U$ can be extended to a linear form on $V$. My idea is to get a basis of $U$, extend it to a basis of $V$ and set the linear form to be zero on the basis elements that are not in $U$? Does this work?

Comment: Yes, it does. But how are the two paragraphs related ? The fact that $V^*\to U^*$ is surjective has nothing to do with quadratic forms.

Comment: ...and you have to be careful: the identification of $V$ with $V^*$ is not canonical and the identification through quadratic forms and dual basis are in general different

Comment: @CaptainLama Because $V$ satisfies the conditions in the first paragraph because I wasn't sure whether the second paragraph holds in every vector space. But now I'm sure that the reasoning with the basis extension always works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two completely different and largely unrelated phenomena at play here.

1) It is well-known that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension, so they are isomorphic as vector spaces. But it is also well-known that they are not *canonically* isomorphic. One way to construct an isomorphism is to choose a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$, then consider the dual basis $(e_i^*)$ of $V^*$, and define $V\to V^*$ by sending $e_i$ to $e_i^*$. This is of course strongly dependent on the choice of the basis $e_i$. In general, an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ is the same as a nondegenerated bilinear form on $V$. Usually, we like it to be either symmetric (which defines a quadratic form) or anti-symmetric (say in characteristic not $2$). The dual basis trick corresponds to choosing a quadratic form that can be diagonalized as $\langle 1,\dots ,1\rangle$ (and the basis $(e_i)$ corresponds to the diagonalization basis).

2) For any vector space, of any dimension, over any field, if $U\subset V$ is a subspace, then the canonical restriction map $V^*\to U^*$ is surjective (at least if we allow an appropriate axiom of choice, if the dimension is infinite). This is for instance because we can take a supplementary subspace $V=U\oplus W$, and extend any linear map $U\to k$ to $V$ by stating that it is $0$ on $W$. A more fancy answer is to say that it is because all vector spaces are injective modules.

The huge difference between those two observations is that the first one relates spaces with their dual (it is a "mixed" map if you want) while the second one deals purely with dual spaces (by comparison we could say it is "homogeneous").